# Nested IF,VLOOKUP Formula

Tags: excel, vlookup, nested-if

I am trying to write a formula to replace my results with a specific text if the returned results are either `N/A`, `0` or `blank`.

However, I can't seem to get it quite right.  This is what I have so far.

```
IF(
    LEN(
        VLOOKUP($E3,'[Global Spend Categories SQL.xlsx]SQL Results USE'!$B$3:$I$4609,6,0)
       )=0,"TO BE CATEGORISED",IF(LEN(
                                VLOOKUP($E3,'[Global Spend Categories SQL.xlsx]SQL Results USE'!$B$3:$I$4609,6,0)
                                )="","TO BE CATEGORISED",VLOOKUP($E3,'[Global Spend Categories SQL.xlsx]SQL Results USE'!$B$3:$I$4609,6,0)
                                 )
        )
```

My formula above is replacing the `0` and `blank` results with "TO BE CATEGORISED", however when I try to add in for `N/A`'s it doesn't work.

Can anyone help with a solution to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is the `N/A` a text string, or is it the error `#N/A`?

Comment: What do yo umean when you try to add in for `N/A`? Also why are you checking for if `LEN()` is empty? Wouldn't that just return `0` if there's no length?  Perhaps `=IF(OR(LEN(VLOOKUP($E3,'[Global Spend Categories SQL.xlsx]SQL Results USE'!$B$3:$I$4609,6,0))=0,VLOOKUP($E3,'[Global Spend Categories SQL.xlsx]SQL Results USE'!$B$3:$I$4609,6,0)=""),"TO BE CATEGORISED",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3,'[Global Spend Categories SQL.xlsx]SQL Results USE'!$B$3:$I$4609,6,0),"TO BE CATEGORISED"))`

Comment: if n/a is an error you can to use iferror formula